# LET REC recursive expression static typing rule

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, type-checking

I'm taking a programming languages course and had a question regarding the typing rules for a recursive `let rec` expression in a static typing system.

To be more specific, we're using the textbook *Essentials of Programming Languages (3e) - Friedman & Wand*.

To give some rough background, here's how the author describes the typing rule for a normal `let` binding expression:

[image]

To briefly describe it for anybody unfamiliar with the notation, `type-of` is a function used to evaluate the type of the given expression.

According to the typing rule, we evaluate `exp1` first, which would give us type $t_1$. Then we extend our current environment so $var$ is mapped to $t_1$. Using this new environment, we evaluate the $body$ of the expression which gives us our final type.

Here's a typical `let` binding example in the OCaml programming language:

```ocaml
let func (x) = x + 1 in (func 3);; (* Outputs -: int=4 *)

let func = fun (x -> x + 1) in (func 3);;
(* Equivalent but better aligned with given typing rule. *)
```

Here's how a `let-rec` recursive binding's typing rule is defined:

[image]

The main problem that I'm having is how to understand the order of evaluation. According to the typing rule, it seems as though we're extending the environment first with $var$ and $p$, but where are we getting the types to map them to from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you discovered the difference between a set of typing rules and an algorithm for type inference.

Typing rules only define a relation among 1) a type environment, 2) a term, and 3) a type. Their purpose is only to precisely define a mathematical relation $\Gamma \vdash t: \tau$.

Once we have such definition, we do not automatically get a type checking algorithm. That is, in general, there is no algorithm described by the rules which, given $\Gamma,t,\tau$, is able to test whether $\Gamma \vdash t: \tau$ holds. (In some cases, such an algorithm could even fail to exist!)

Similarly, we do not automatically obtain a type inference algorithm, which given $\Gamma,t$ is able to find a related $\tau$ (when it exists).

The type checking/type inference algorithm must be devised independently.

Now, it *is* true that in many cases the algorithms can follow the rules quite closely. The rule for non-recursive LET you mention is one nice example, since it is clear how to turn it into an algorithm. For recursive LETs, we are not that lucky.

A typical strategy to type check/infer recursive LETs is to introduce a fresh type variable in the environment, and then perform type checking on the body while generating a set of constraints. For instance, consider this example

```
let-rec f (x: int) = 1 + f(x) in f(0)
```

We discover immediately that `f : int -> ???`. Let's introduce a fresh type variable `R` for the result, and say `f : int -> R`.

We then type check `1 + f(x)` assuming the environment `f: int -> R , x: int`.
Here `+` is applied to arguments `1: int` and `f(x): R`. Assuming `+` requires its arguments to be of the same type, this forces the constraint `int = R`.
If `+` also returns the same type, we obtain another constraint `int = R` (redundant, in this case).

Finally, we solve the constraints, discovering `R = int`.

Note that in the general case we might be less lucky, since more complex types could be involved.

```
let-rec f(x: int) = (2, fst(f(x-1)))
```

Here, we discover `f: int -> R`, then we see that `R` must be a pair type `R = A*B`, then `A=int` (because of the `2`). Moreover, we get `f(x-1):R` so `fst(f(x-1)): A`, hence `B=A`. We conclude `f: int->(int*int)`.

It is not trivial to generate these constraints, or to solve them (usually through a *unification* algorithm). In the scientific literature we can find several algorithms which perform this, but they are not obvious at first.

Answer (score 4):

Typing rules are not "code". There is no "evaluation order". All the rule is saying is: if we're given *some* $t_{res}$ and $t_{var}$ (and $t$ and $tenv$ and ...) such that the first two equations hold, then we can conclude the bottom equation. *How* you come up with the $t_{res}$ and $t_{var}$ is out of scope and not specified.

That said, often we *can* read these types of rules as programs, but they are *logic* programs. In this context, the answer to your question is easy: you simply stick logic variables everywhere. Unification will handle the data transfer in whatever direction is needed.